# Redis bull connection error ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: redis, connection

Actually i'am using Redis with Bee Queue and i would like to try Bull the problem is i'am unable to connect to my Digital Ocean Redis server.

I'am using node_redis

```
const client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_DIGITAL_OCEAN)
```

In Bee Queue this is working for me

```
const Queue = require('bee-queue')
const addQueue = new Queue('test', { redis: client, isWorker: false })
```

In Bull i tried this is not working

```
 const Queue = require('bull')
 const addQueue = new Queue('test', { client })
```

Or

```
const Queue = require('bull')
const addQueue = new Queue('test', client)
```

But it's not working i have

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

What i'am doing wrong ? thanks